# cmake using SDL2 and SDL2_Image via FetchContent

Tags: c++, c, cmake, sdl, sdl-2

I've a small cmake project that uses SDL via FetchContent, this work well with just SDL.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(sdl_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

include(FetchContent)
Set(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET FALSE)

FetchContent_Declare(
        SDL2
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL.git
        GIT_TAG release-2.26.3
        GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
        GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(SDL2)
include_directories(${SDL2_SOURCE_DIR}/include})

add_executable(sdl_test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(sdl_test SDL2::SDL2main SDL2::SDL2-static)
```

I try to use the same approach to include SDL_Image, however I can not get it to work.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(sdl_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

include(FetchContent)
Set(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET FALSE)

FetchContent_Declare(
        SDL2
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL.git
        GIT_TAG release-2.26.3
        GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
        GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(SDL2)
include_directories(${SDL2_SOURCE_DIR}/include})

FetchContent_Declare(
        SDL2_image
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_image.git
        GIT_TAG release-2.6.3
        GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
        GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(SDL2_image)
include_directories(${SDL2IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS}/include})

add_executable(sdl_test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(sdl_test SDL2::SDL2main SDL2::SDL2-static SDL2_image::SDL2_image-static)
```

Produce the following error:

```
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "SDL2ImageExports" ...) includes target "SDL2_image" which requires target "SDL2" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:30 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "sdl_test" links to:

    SDL2_image::SDL2_image-static

  but the target was not found.  Possible reasons include:

    * There is a typo in the target name.
    * A find_package call is missing for an IMPORTED target.
    * An ALIAS target is missing.
```

*Note: Maybe some people dislike using FetchContent, however I like it and been using for many other dependencies in the past, so I'm trying to make this approach to work.*

Comment: Out of curiosity, is `include_directories(${SDL2_SOURCE_DIR}/include})` really necessary when you later do `target_link_libraries(sdl_test SDL2::SDL2main SDL2::SDL2-static)`?

Comment: What's the value of `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` when you `FetchContent_MakeAvailable(SDL2_image)`? It needs to be `"STATIC"` for you to use `SDL2_image::SDL2_image-static`. ([link to source](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_image/blob/SDL2/CMakeLists.txt))

Comment: I'm a `cmake` novice. But, I assume you've looked at `ExternalProject_Add`? Did you try this to see if it behaves better? In addition to _fetching_ content, don't you have to tell it to _build_ the external project? Also, could the `-static` be an issue? Did you try _without_ it as the package may build the dynamic version but _not_ the static version by default?

Comment: @CraigEstey `FetchContent` makes the fetched project part of the same generated buildsystem instead of a separate generated buildsystem (`ExternalProject`). The approaches are quite different and each require different considerations. You don't need to do anything to tell fetched targets to be built other than link whatever uses it to it. As for the `-static`, see my second comment.

Comment: @user For me, I'd probably want the external project to stay external. I saw your comment [and looked at the link--it's quite _thorough_ ;-)]. But, it's been 2 hours and OP hasn't responded to your comment(s). If it were me, I'd build the `SDL*` images with dynamic, get _that_ working, and then figure out how to get the static versions working. So, for me, I'd do simple first: external projects and dynamic. Then, add back the other options, one by one.

Comment: I can remove the include_directories and still work without SDL_Image but still not work with SDL_Image, same error

Comment: I don't want to use ExternalProject_Add, that implied to usually implied to have the project as a git submodule of my project, as someone point it out I want just to be external, a reference to a particular tag/version

Comment: BUILD_SHARED_LIBS: value is OFF before FetchContent_Declare SDL2_image, I try to force to "STATIC" and get CMake Error: The INTERFACE_SDL2_SHARED property of "SDL2" does
not agree with the value of SDL2_SHARED already determined, I change it to OFF and get exactly the same error that in my original post

Comment: I try as well to build it not -static, target_link_libraries(sdl_test SDL2::SDL2 SDL2_image::SDL2_image), and get similar error : CMake Error: install(EXPORT "SDL2ImageExports" ...) includes target "SDL2_image" which requires target "SDL2" that is not in any export set.

Comment: whoops. I meant "OFF" and not "STATIC". but if it was already "OFF", then I don't know the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create an [issue](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_image/issues/338#issuecomment-1447289363) on SLD_Image repository, and they give the following answer, that actually work.

*The CMake script of SDL2_image builds only a shared or static library, not both.*
*So you need to set BUILD_SHARED_LIBS to a false-ish value.*

*Also, you need to disable the installation targets of SDL2_image (this has been fixed in git).*

*So your cmake script should become:*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(sdl_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

include(FetchContent)
Set(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET FALSE)

FetchContent_Declare(
        SDL2
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL.git
        GIT_TAG release-2.26.3
        GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
        GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(SDL2)

FetchContent_Declare(
        SDL2_image
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_image.git
        GIT_TAG release-2.6.3
        GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
        GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
)

# START ADDITION
set(SDL2IMAGE_INSTALL OFF)
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS FALSE)
# END ADDITION

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(SDL2_image)

add_executable(sdl_test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(sdl_test SDL2::SDL2main SDL2::SDL2-static SDL2_image::SDL2_image-static)
```

They clarify further the behaviour.

*SDL2 is able to create a shared and static library, configurable through `SDL_SHARED` and `SDL_STATIC`.*
*Both are enabled by default.*
*SDL2_image is only able to configure one at a time (using `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`).*

*SDL3's default has changed: `SDL_SHARED` and `SDL_STATIC` are initialized by `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` (during first configuration).*
*If `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` is not defined, then only `SDL_SHARED` is enabled.*
*If `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` is defined, it can build tdecides what one).*
*Either ways `SDL_SHARED` and `SDL_STATIC` remain the ultimate options.*

*It isn't implemented yet, but SDL3_image will probably follow the same behavior as SDL3 and be able to build both shared and static configurations.*

Comment: Thanks, glad you solve it.  For me just adding set(SDL2IMAGE_INSTALL OFF) fix the problem.

Comment: But with using SDL2IMAGE with SDL2 using Cmake Fetch doesn't work out in the end because.  SDL2IMAGE is expected to be installed in the SDL2 include folder.  So, If you are going to disable the SDL2IMAGE_INSTALL you will need to write script that copies the necessary SDL2IMAGE include files into SDL2 Include folder in SDL2 Binary directory.

Comment: An obvious workaround, though not useful if you are trying to include SDL2 and SDL2Image as part of your project, is to INSTALL SDL2 using CMAKE Install.  Then SDL2IMAGE will find the SDL2 target on the machine (based on the question error message).

Comment: Sorry, I can't edit comments after a certain time, for my second comment from top, the only file you need to copy from SDL2IMAGE SOURCE DIR is SDL_image.h

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The answer that I'm outlining here is just a possible solution, it may not work. But it's worth a try. The best way to make this work is to **not use** the `SHALLOW` fetch, but **I assume here that you don't want that**.</strike>
Correction from @user.

---

**Possible solution:**

Most of the people in the comments focus on the "wrong" part of the error message. What you should be focusing on are the first 2 lines, i.e.:

```
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "SDL2ImageExports" ...) includes target "SDL2_image" which requires target "SDL2" that is not in any export set.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:30 (target_link_libraries):
```

Because the target is not found, the actual library that you link against doesn't exist. Hence why the `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` option doesn't do anything.

It says that `SDL2_image` requires the target `SDL2` which is defined in the previous `FetchContent` invokation, but this isn't available to the other one during build time. The real question now is, how to make it available.

I believe the only way is pretty much a "hacky" way. Let's check what the `SDL_Image`s `CMakeLists.txt` looks like, specifically the line right here:
[Line 748](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_image/blob/release-2.6.3/CMakeLists.txt#L748).

It seems to be that `SDL2` as a package is referred to as `SDL2main`, please note that in `versions 3.0.0+` it's just `SDL3`.

So the best chance at making this work would probably be to change the first `FetchContent_Declare` as such (Note that you need `CMake 3.24+`):

```
FetchContent_Declare(
        SDL2main # <--- new name of our target
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL.git
        GIT_TAG release-2.26.3
        GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
        GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
        OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE #<--- and we also need to add this
)
```

This should hopefully override subsequent `find_package(SDL2main)` calls and might fix your issue.

---

**Last option:** if the above won't work, you could just "not build" the `SDL2_Image` samples, i.e. by enforcing `SDL2IMAGE_SAMPLES` to be `False`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. I did the rename to SDL2 to SDL2main, I add the OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE  and set SDL2IMAGE_SAMPLES  to off (forced), and did remove the SHALLOW as well, and now the error is *CMake Error: install(EXPORT "SDL2ImageExports" ...) includes target "SDL2_image" which requires target "SDL2" that is not in any export set.*

Comment: forgot to mention I've *cmake version 3.25.2*

Comment: @JuanMedina did you clear the caches, i.e. removed the build folder? Also regarding the shallow options, it is a bit more complicated and isn't only about removing the `SHALLOW` option. I know that it has some very weird behavior that is more related to `git` then `CMake`. In regards to the `SHALLOW` option I would start by creating a completely new and clean project. This is based on my experience.

Comment: @JuanMedina removing the `SHALLOW` option should fix the issue, because in that case you are going to download **all** the subrepositories in that git project and building them from scratch. So if you don't see `zlib` and other dependencies being built, then it is not `SHALLOW FALSE`.

Comment: Milan, I thought `GIT_SHALLOW` and `GIT_SUBMODULES` are mostly orthogonal (mostly do different things). It sounds like you mean to be talking about `GIT_SUBMODULES`, which by default (if unspecified), ExternalProject fetches all submodules.

Comment: @user that's what I'm saying here. With the `GIT_SHALLOW` option externalproject_add / fetchcontent doesn't download git submodules.

Comment: weird. that's not what has happened for me in my experience using `GIT_SHALLOW`. For  example, FetchContent of `git@github.com:ericniebler/range-v3.git` with `GIT_SHALLOW` still fetches the `doc/gh-pages` submodule. I need to explicitly say `GIT_SUBMODULES ""` (fetch no submodules)

Comment: @user are you specifying a tag?

Comment: yep: `GIT_TAG "0.12.0"` why do you ask?

Comment: @user ahh two things - my bad first and foremost secondly you're right. Too bad I can't correct my comments. I've mistaken a different command for git shallow clone. I was asking due to the fact that shallow only works if you specify a tag in `CMake` but that is completely unrelated to this as my brain experienced a huge segfault. Consider my previous comments void

Comment: I understand the confusion, I use shallow to just get the last commit from that particular tag and no previous commits/history, that make the clone process faster

Comment: I find something interesting, I may try latter:  find-package args in the docs https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html#integrating-with-find-package

Answer (score 0):

So basically, this is my implementation.  I turned off SDL2_image installation because that is where the bug.  Because we are including SDL2 in our project using FetchContent, SDL2_image install option won't find the include/SDL2 folder to install SDL2_image.h .  After I use fetchcontent to get both SDL2 and SDL2_image in my project, I copy the SDL2_image.h file my self.

```
include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
  SDL2
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL.git
  GIT_TAG        release-2.28.5
)

FetchContent_Declare(
  SDL2_image
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_image.git
  GIT_TAG        release-2.6.3
)

set(SDL2IMAGE_INSTALL OFF) # this is an SDL2 Cmake bug so turning it off 
# and handling the copying of files myself.

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(SDL2 SDL2_image)

#SG is my project name, hence `SG_SOURCE_DIR`
#Replace this for your project's
include(${SG_SOURCE_DIR}/Scripts/CopySpecificFiles.cmake)
CopySpecificFiles(
  ${SDL2_image_SOURCE_DIR}/SDL_image.h
  ${SDL2_BINARY_DIR}/include/SDL2
  custom-copy-specific-files
)
add_dependencies(custom-copy-specific-files SDL2_image)

target_link_libraries(SG PUBLIC SDL2 SDL2_image)
target_link_directories(SG PUBLIC ${SDL2_BINARY_DIR}/include)
```

Here is the code for the CopySpecificFiles function:

```
function(CopySpecificFiles IN_FILES IN_DST_FOLDER OUT_CMD)
message(STATUS "COPY SPECIFIC FILES")
set(${IN_FILES} ${IN_FILES};) # ensures that it is a list
set(COPIED_FILES)
foreach(_hdr IN LISTS ${IN_FILES})
    get_filename_component(_name "${_hdr}" NAME)    
    set(_bin_hdr ${IN_DST_FOLDER}/${_name})
    list(APPEND COPIED_FILES "${_bin_hdr}")
    add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${_bin_hdr} 
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different "${_hdr}" "${_bin_hdr}"
        DEPENDS ${_hdr} COMMENT "COPYING SPECIFIC FILE: ${_bin_hdr}" VERBATIM)
    add_custom_target(${OUT_CMD} ALL DEPENDS ${COPIED_FILES})
endforeach()
endfunction()
```